# Why CDC records nothing while being enabled?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I enabled Change Data Capture on some tables in a Microsoft SQL 2008 database. Both of the following queries return 1:

```
select top 1 is_cdc_enabled from sys.databases where name = N'<DatabaseName>'

select top 1 T.[is_tracked_by_cdc]
    from sys.tables as T
        left join sys.schemas as S
        on T.[schema_id] = S.[schema_id]
    where S.[name] = N'<SchemaName>' and T.[name] = N'<TableName>'
```

but when I change the data of a concerned table, `cdc.<SchemaName>_<TableName>_CT` remains empty.

Why?

Comment: Why do you use `LEFT JOIN` and `WHERE` that actually makes it `INNER JOIN` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check to make sure the SQL Agent is running, and that there is a capture job created that is enabled and running for the CDC instance, it should show Change Data Capture Collection Agent / executing.

Comment: Exact. The job was in failed state, and the history displayed the errors. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: Among 2 steps: Step 1: starting change data capture  works fine, Step 2: Change data capture collection agent not working and also I didn't get any error. How to identify the issue of step2.